Matching ID and non-exact date on one excel sheet to the same ID and closest and greater date on a different excel sheet
I have a list of 126 4 digit IDs (sometimes the ID duplicates) and all of these IDs match to dates in serial format (ex: 45062). In another sheet, that's acting like a reference sheet, is a log of every ID and every exact date (also ins serial format) associated with those IDs.
Here's my goal: Say I have ID: 3456, and it's date is June 5th, 2024. I want to match that ID with a date in the other sheet that's closest to June5th 2024 but is also larger in value. For example, in Sheet2, ID 3456 could have 4 dates: June 4th 2024, June 10th 2024, July 15th 2024, and august 20th 2024. I'm trying to write a formula so that excel only matches ID 3456 with date June 5th 2024 in sheet1 with June 10th 2024 from sheet2. ** but on excel all my dates are in serial format**
I tried
 =IFERROR(
    MIN(
        IF(
            (Sheet2!$A$2:$A$3045 = F2) *
            (ISNUMBER(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$3045)),
            Sheet2!$C$2:$C$3045
        )
    ),
    ""
)

and kept getting 0s

Hey, since you're getting 0s, I'm wondering whether your dates are in text format (though they represent date serial). You can easy test it by adding for example IF(…,10). Anyway, could you please test by converting those values to numerical by IF( (Sheet2!$A$2:$A$3045 = F2) *(ISNUMBER(--Sheet2!$C$2:$C$3045)), --Sheet2!$C$2:$C$3045)?

This formula is in cell D55
=MIN(IF((A59:A67=B54)*(B59:B67>=B55),B59:B67,DATE(9999,12,31)))

The formula first set all dates which is earlier then the lookup to 9999.12.31, and then get the smallest of them. Then the minimum value will be the first later date then the lookup for the specific ID.
With the actual ranges assumed that the dates are in column H:
=MIN(IF((Sheet2!$A$2:$A$3045=F2)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$3045>=H2),Sheet2!$C$2:$C$3045,DATE(9999,12,31)))


Thanks so much for the help, I tried the formula and all my dates were set as 9999.12.31 (like you said), and I don't know how to proceed. What I mean is I don't know how to " get the smallest of them. Then the minimum value will be the first later date then the lookup for the specific ID". Sorry if the answer is super obvious, I am rather new to using formulas in excel

Pls. check the formula is identical to the one at the bottom of the answer. Especially the relation operators, and that F2 and H2 contains correct values.

I re-created your exact example and it only said false :( I may have to do some stuff manually haha

Can you add a screenshot into your post of the relevant parts of the sheets with sample data?

Sure thing, I added a screenshot to the original post. I tried to re-create your example to test whether the formula would run

The problem is that in your case the cell contents are strings. This mix up the comparison of the values.Apply  the local date format to ensure that the cells contain date numbers. Dates are stored as serial numbers and the cell formatting transform a number to a date visualization.

Would this work?
=LET(
    id_1, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,
    date_1, Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10,
    id_2, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10,
    date_2, Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10,
    result, IFERROR(
        MAP(
            id_1,
            date_1,
            LAMBDA(i, d, MIN(FILTER(date_2, (id_2 = i) * (date_2 >= d))))
        ),
        ""
    ),
    result
)




I tried writing out your example to test, my version of excel doesn't have  the "LET" function, so I will update and report back

Thanks for testing. Could you please tell me the version  (File > About > Version)? LET is available from Excel 2021, but MAP etc. are available only in Microsoft 365. I'll try a different way tomorrow.
